# java use jvm proxy setting still returns 407 while postman works fine

Tags: java, postman, http-proxy

Here is my postman config
[image]

it works just find, can obtain my target url content, while in intellij, the code is like below,

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("java.net.useSystemProxies", "true");
    String url = "http://xxxx/";

    String charset = "UTF-8";
    URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
    String result = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response))
            .lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

I also have my jvm args added like

```
-Dhttp.proxyUser=username -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhost -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
```

but above code keeps saying: Server returned HTTP response code: 407 for URL

Can someone tell me anything I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

find answer from [HTTP Error 407 Proxy authentication required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17183277/http-error-407-proxy-authentication-required) and it worked, need to add below code

```
    Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator()
    {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password".toCharArray());
        }
    });
```